# Interaction between continuous and categorical variable in R: is there a way to include all categories?

Tags: r, linear-regression, categorical-data, interaction

Is there a way to run a linear regression with R with interaction terms between continuous and categorical variable but excluding the continuous variable itself?

I am studying relation between housing rents and dwell floorspace. There are four different regions in my dataset, and I assume that the relation is different across them. I am using linear regression of `rent` on `region`and  interaction between `floorspace` and `region`, and I want to have coefficients on `region` and on interaction terms, but using `lm` with interaction term forces `floorspace` to appear as independent variable, too.

That's how it goes:

```
lm(formula = rent ~ factor(region) + factor(region) * floorspace, 
    data = mydataset)

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                       4.67252    0.06792  68.792  < 2e-16 ***
factor(region)2                  -0.39859    0.09453  -4.216 2.52e-05 ***
factor(region)3                  -0.23631    0.17870  -1.322 0.186078    
factor(region)4                  -0.49076    0.10329  -4.751 2.07e-06 ***
floorspace                       -0.38658    0.01539 -25.119  < 2e-16 ***
factor(region)2:floorspace        0.20481    0.02145   9.550  < 2e-16 ***
factor(region)3:floorspace       -0.00884    0.03987  -0.222 0.824552    
factor(region)4:floorspace        0.08022    0.02348   3.416 0.000638 ***
```

What I want instead is this:

```
Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                       4.67252    0.06792  68.792  < 2e-16 ***
factor(region)2                  -0.39859    0.09453  -4.216 2.52e-05 ***
factor(region)3                  -0.23631    0.17870  -1.322 0.186078    
factor(region)4                  -0.49076    0.10329  -4.751 2.07e-06 ***
factor(region)1:floorspace       -0.38658    0.01539 -25.119  < 2e-16 ***
factor(region)2:floorspace       -0.18177    ???????   ?????  ??????? 
factor(region)3:floorspace       -0.39543    ???????   ?????  ???????    
factor(region)4:floorspace       -0.30636    ???????   ?????  ???????
```

Reason is that from interpretation point of view it makes more sense to show effect of `floorspace` for each region separately, instead of showing it for  `region=1` with `floorspace`, and the rest as difference between the effect for the given region and the `region=1`

Comment: Make a test data set with: `mydataset = data.frame(region=sample(1:4, 100,TRUE), floorspace=runif(100))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll make a test data set with: `mydataset = data.frame(rent=runif(100), region=sample(1:4, 100,TRUE), floorspace=runif(100))`

Take the linear term in `floorspace` out of the formula by subtraction:

```
    summary(lm(formula = rent ~ factor(region) + factor(region) * floorspace - floorspace, data=mydataset))

    Call:
    lm(formula = rent ~ factor(region) + factor(region) * floorspace - 
        floorspace, data = mydataset)

    Residuals:
         Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
    -0.52917 -0.26151  0.01225  0.24816  0.52392 

    Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)                 0.50329    0.09238   5.448 4.23e-07 ***
    factor(region)2             0.01331    0.13804   0.096    0.923    
    factor(region)3             0.05716    0.16860   0.339    0.735    
    factor(region)4            -0.03252    0.16234  -0.200    0.842    
    factor(region)1:floorspace  0.16273    0.22805   0.714    0.477    
    factor(region)2:floorspace  0.01638    0.19894   0.082    0.935    
    factor(region)3:floorspace -0.14251    0.20262  -0.703    0.484    
    factor(region)4:floorspace -0.05094    0.24191  -0.211    0.834
```

Comment: Doesn't `A*B` in a formula expand to `A + B + A:B`? You can simply do `factor(region) + factor(region) : floorspace`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I noticed that I should not put `-floorspace` anywhere. At least, the above code will not work if I put it before the interaction term. Are there any other constraints to take into account?

Comment: I think @RuiBarradas has a neater formula for the same model spec.